How to run httpd:2.4 offical image with httpd.conf of outside the container
On httpd offical web document page(https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd), it does not show how to use the image with my-httpd.conf that out side the container, my target is that once httpd.conf is updated, I just only need to restart the contanier, not to rebuid the image then start it.

To persist data across builds:  https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

This question is similar to: How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in Docker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
